# Firebase Database Rest Api: How to get the next page when use LimitToLast()

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have asked several questions about the use of `LimitToLast()` And `EndAt()` Also The Paginating backward from the end of The Data, Because I am trying to fetch the first 10 most viewed data using `OrderBy("Views")` Then Get the other 10 When Scroll Down.

When fetching the first 10 data Ordered By **Views**, I get it correctly, but **my problem** is how do I get the **Correct Node** so as I can use it to get the (Previous Page) which contains the other 10 data
without any problem even if there are nodes with the same value of Views.

As it is assumed that we have to get the node that has the lowest value of Views and store it in `string` and when fetching the other 10 data we use it like this :
`OrderBy("Views").LimitToLast(11).EndAt(LastValue,LastId)`
But I always get incorrect and often duplicate results, especially if there is data with the same value of Views.
[My Json Stracture 30 Nodes](https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22) :

```
{
  "-Mps4qWpgU-L5E3OfAMD" : {
    "Text" : 1,
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mps4qoSPhzh3Hzu1i2y" : {
    "Text" : 2,
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mps4qxhzwbQ80snD3jF" : {
    "Text" : 3,
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mps4r60gkcsFjI33d-q" : {
    "Text" : 4,
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mps4rF4Ku1X1FIyR0M8" : {
    "Text" : 5,
    "Views" : 20
  }
 More...
}
```

My C# Code:

```
    public class PostData
    {
        public int Views{get;set;}
        public string Text{get;set;}
    }
//Get First 10
var Data = await firebaseclient
                .Child("Education/")
                .OrderBy("Views")
                .LimitToLast(10)
                .OnceAsync<PostData>();
                //Order The Data By Descending on their Views And Key
                var sortedData = Data.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Object.Views).ThenByDescending(x=>x.Key);
                //Save The Last Id (lowest value of Views) and his Value Of Views
               string LastID = sortedData.Last().Key;
               int LastValue = sortedData.Last().Object.Views;

//Get More (Previous Page)
var Data = await firebaseclient
                .Child("Education/")
                .OrderBy("Views")
                .EndAt(LastValue,LastID)
                .LimitToLast(11)
                .OnceAsync<PostData>();
                //Order The Data By Descending on their Views And Key
                var sortedData = Data.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Object.Views).ThenByDescending(x=>x.Key);
                //Update The Last Id and his Value Of Views
               string LastID = sortedData.Last().Key;
               int LastValue = sortedData.Last().Object.Views;
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/jegeboc/edit?js,console) shows that the correct order for the nodes is:

```
"-Mps4qWpgU-L5E3OfAMD": {"Text":1,"Views":20},
"-Mps4qoSPhzh3Hzu1i2y": {"Text":2,"Views":20},
"-Mps4qxhzwbQ80snD3jF": {"Text":3,"Views":20},
"-Mps4r60gkcsFjI33d-q": {"Text":4,"Views":20},
"-Mps4rF4Ku1X1FIyR0M8": {"Text":5,"Views":20},
"-Mps4rOgbcEeIZ-Kyi0I": {"Text":6,"Views":20},
"-Mps4rYAe5dIPytLvk4E": {"Text":7,"Views":20},
"-Mps4rgdzKlylkoeOTGc": {"Text":8,"Views":20},
"-Mps4rpqUdlVdfsatirv": {"Text":9,"Views":20},
"-Mps4rzCa-YS60CqXzfy": {"Text":10,"Views":20},
"-Mps4s7am1ZCuLtBp0nk": {"Text":11,"Views":20},
"-Mps4sGxBOgFsTLFSqMk": {"Text":12,"Views":20},
"-Mps4sQ9CLYNFQ4Uynhb": {"Text":13,"Views":20},
"-Mps4sZY5egXpf5_CmFi": {"Text":14,"Views":20},
"-Mps4shiJxx2dQVwen-Y": {"Text":15,"Views":20},
"-Mps4srZmVvPvImOf48D": {"Text":16,"Views":20},
"-Mps4tQpS0qYHlwHd8jJ": {"Text":18,"Views":20},
"-Mps4tZujfdt-q1EnjGq": {"Text":19,"Views":20},
"-Mps4thzzjBtFaRyRcxu": {"Text":20,"Views":20},
"-Mps4tr7SE6t7qZc2513": {"Text":21,"Views":20},
"-Mps4u0-6dOElpUhjzYY": {"Text":22,"Views":20},
"-Mps4u9G_112glr6ijQl": {"Text":23,"Views":20},
"-Mps4uJ-j75wAdmth6lb": {"Text":24,"Views":20},
"-Mps4uS8BCBb7FASfZJ5": {"Text":25,"Views":20},
"-Mps4uaMoWvGEvKNCcVc": {"Text":26,"Views":20},
"-Mps4ujkjYW5CeqSFPqU": {"Text":27,"Views":20},
"-Mps4usz_FyTYx49oz6e": {"Text":28,"Views":20},
"-Mps4v1HhVdmlOOZhYs_": {"Text":29,"Views":20},
"-Mps4vB9i4F0irpPeRgz": {"Text":30,"Views":20},
"-Mps4tH5mnQlklXP5o3I": {"Text":17,"Views":50}
```

If we order by `Views` and take the last 10 notes with this query: [orderBy="Views"&limitToLast=10](https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/70215045.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=10) we get these results:

```
{
  "-Mps4tH5mnQlklXP5o3I" : { "Text" : 17, "Views" : 50 },
  "-Mps4u0-6dOElpUhjzYY" : { "Text" : 22, "Views" : 20 },
  "-Mps4u9G_112glr6ijQl" : { "Text" : 23, "Views" : 20 },
  "-Mps4uJ-j75wAdmth6lb" : { "Text" : 24, "Views" : 20 },
  "-Mps4uS8BCBb7FASfZJ5" : { "Text" : 25, "Views" : 20 },
  "-Mps4uaMoWvGEvKNCcVc" : { "Text" : 26, "Views" : 20 },
  "-Mps4ujkjYW5CeqSFPqU" : { "Text" : 27, "Views" : 20 },
  "-Mps4usz_FyTYx49oz6e" : { "Text" : 28, "Views" : 20 },
  "-Mps4v1HhVdmlOOZhYs_" : { "Text" : 29, "Views" : 20 },
  "-Mps4vB9i4F0irpPeRgz" : { "Text" : 30, "Views" : 20 }
}
```

When we order them the same as above, the first one of these results in the original list is:

```
"-Mps4u0-6dOElpUhjzYY": {"Text":22,"Views":20},
```

So those are the value and key you need to use in your subsequent call to get the page above the last one: [orderBy="Views"&limitToLast=10&endAt=20,"-Mps4u0-6dOElpUhjzYY"](https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/70215045.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=10&endAt=20,%22-Mps4u0-6dOElpUhjzYY%22). As far as I can see this gives the expected results.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am grateful to you :) I ran several tests and the results were correct and I got 3 pages with no duplicate data but I noticed a problem when I call GetMore() function to fetch more after the 3 pages it is supposed to return `0` nodes or null data because there is no other data but in fact Will return the **first two nodes** Please you can see the results here in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1KGo7B)

Comment: i think the problem when i call `GetMore3()` in the fiddle It will sort the data and the last node will be `-Mps4qoSPhzh3Hzu1i2y` But it's supposed to be `-Mps4qWpgU-L5E3OfAMD` Although it re-sort the data in the same way
using `var sorted = full.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Value.Views).ThenByDescending(x=>x.Key);`

Comment: The order in my answer comes from the jsbin, which comes from the SDK. So I'm pretty sure that is the correct order according to the product. If your code gives a different order, that would explain the problem - but I can't say why that is since `"-Mps4qWpgU-L5E3OfAMD" < "-Mps4qoSPhzh3Hzu1i2y" -> true`.

Comment: True, I now realize that the problem is in the code, but I want to know what type of `object` is for firebase push id, I mean how did you know that 
`"-Mps4qWpgU-L5E3OfAMD" < "-Mps4qoSPhzh3Hzu1i2y" == true` Because firebase push id is not `string` or `integer` or `long` or `double` or `DateTime` Because in fact, these keys can only be **sorted** correctly after knowing the type of the object,Anyway, thank you very much, I understand everything now :)

Comment: A push ID *is* (and any key in Firebase Realtime Database is) (by definition) a string, hence it is ordered lexicographically. If you want to learn more about their properties, that make them so useful for keys in the database, have a look at https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Comment: It's really amazing information about these keys, I understood how to Re-Sort These Keys Correctly,Thank you for helping me with all my questions, Have a nice day